# PDF Form: make text field visible on print

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pdf, pdf-form

I need to develop a script to programmatically change all the text fields' property in PDF Form from "Visible but doesn't print" to "Visible" (Adobe Acrobat Pro screenshot attached below)

[image]

**Problem:**

Doing it in Adobe would not work since I need to perform that operation on hundreds of PDF documents. Therefore, I need a library that would be able to access and modify this property from a PDF form.

**Requirements:**

Any scripting language such as JavaScript or Python and a library thereof goes. It is quite important that PDF is modified "in-place" (i.e. form fields are modified within a PDF instead of creating a completely new *empty* PDF Form)

**What I have tried so far:**

Node.js - [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib/v/1.6.0) (couldn't find a method to modify the abovementioned property of PDF Form field)

Node.js - [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) (couldn't find a method to modify the abovementioned property of PDF Form field)